# How do eradicate pad to pad clearance with-in the component in Eagle Tool?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-layers

I tried clearing the error by defining Rules and net Class, but that does not happen. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to not use Eagle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last version of EAGLE I used has a sticky 'accept' button when running the DRC, after that further DRC runs will ignore them.

I can't tell what your dimensions are, but as far as the DRC rules settings, the pads would would be in the clearance dialog with the pad / pad row/column setting make sure you are using the correct units.

That being said those inter-pad distances look really tight (no scale to compare to, but given the labels I'm thinking 2.54mm or 1.27mm spacing).  Don't forget that even if the board house can make a 3mil spacing board, the fact that you may have to solder pins in and accidentally bridge them during the process may create difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own symbol instead, with long holes instead of round holes.  5 pin connector like that takes no time at all.  Or round holes with smaller outer diameter.